# Know when a ProgressDialog is hidden

Tags: android, progressdialog

`ProgressDialog` are great for blocking interaction with UI however the `ProgressDialog` is 'dismissed' when the user clicks the back button or clicks outside the `ProgressDialog`.

I am displaying this when I fetch some data from the internet and as soon as the `ProgressDialog` is no longer visible, I would like to stop fetching the files as well.

Here us what I have tried:

```
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()){
            @Override
            public void onStop(){
                super.onStop();
                FeedProcessor.processingMustStop(); // stop fetching the RSS feeds
            }
        };
```

However, it doesn't work.
**Please suggest a solution**

Comment: you want to hide the dialog or dismiss it. you can use `isShowing()` return true if the dialog is showing

Comment: @Raghunandan maybe I should override `hide()`

Comment: or just look at the answer below. But i am confused on whehter you meant dismiss or hide?

Comment: @Raghunandan what method is called when the user clicks outside the `ProgressDialog` ?? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle the case when the `Dialog` is dismissed, you need to use the [`DialogInterface.OnDismissListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html).

```
pDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener(){
    void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog){
        //Do your stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Didnt work :( what method is called when the user clicks outside the ProgressDialog ??

Comment: The "cancel" event. If you want to capture only cancel events, use the  [`DialogInterface.OnCancelListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnCancelListener.html) and the [`setOnCancelListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnCancelListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener)) as above. However, the dismiss listener is supposed to cater to all events that lead to the dismissal of the [`Dialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html).

Comment: @LittleChild `dismiss()` i guess. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss(). you can use `isShowing()` returns true if its shwoing. `hide()` Hide the dialog, but do not dismiss it.

Comment: I made an override on all the suspected methods, `cancel()` , `dismiss()` , `hide()` and put a `Log.v()` in there. None of them were called.

Comment: @LittleChild did check using `isShwoing()`? what does it return true or false?. it retruns a boolean value true means dialog is still showing false means dialog dismissed. can you post more info on how you show your dialog and override those methods?

Comment: @LittleChild if use `hide()` its not dismissed so should show true using `isShowing()` and if you use `dismiss()` it should show false. So what does `isShowing()` return?

Comment: The listeners just arent called

Comment: @LittleChild that is strange i don't think you are doing it right!. post more info

Comment: where do you call `dismiss()` or `hide()` and pls post it as part of your question

Comment: I am not calling it at all. It gets called, automatically, when back key is pressed. I need to override that behavior. Also, it *disappears* when the user clicks outside the `ProgressDialog` area

Comment: in `onPreExecute` of the `AsyncTask` responsible for fetching the Feeds

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35156/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-little-child)